# Delphi 2009 JQueryWidget in ISAPI

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, intraweb

I'm trying to use TIWJQueryWidget in a Delphi 2009 ISAPI application, and it's not working.  I started with this tutorial : http://www.hadihariri.com/Blogs/Delphi/20080117.aspx.

When I follow the tuorial creating a stand-alone IW application, it works like a charm.  However, when I create an ISAPI application and do the same thing, I cannot seem to get it to work.  In the HTML that is generated, the source for the js files is being rendered as "/test/TestJQuery2.dll/test/TestJQuery2.dll/Files/jquery.js"... which then can't be found.  If I manually change the resulting SRC to "/test/TestJQuery2.dll/Files/jquery.js" the file can be found.

I think this is some combination of the various Internal File settings in the server controller... but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using Delphi 2009, Update 3.  Interaweb 10.0.0

Is this maybe a bug with Intraweb?

Comment: After more investigation, I found that the issue not really with this JQueryWidget, but rather with the "ContentFiles" of the widget.  The same issue is with the ContentFiles of the Server Controller form as well!

When you add a .js file, the path to the file does not render properly.  A css file, or any other file it seems does render correctly.

I worked around the problem by adding the cs files to the HtmlHeader property.  it works, but it's a hack.

I'd like to know the "proper" solution.